# Trace Class: Relativeness

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a selfadjoint:
$$H\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad H=H^*$$

Denote trace class:
$$\mathcal{B}_1(\mathcal{H}):=\{A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\mathrm{Tr}|A|<\infty\}$$

> Does it hold true:
>   $$0\leq A\leq B:\quad BH\in\mathcal{B}_1(\mathcal{H})\implies AH\in\mathcal{B}_1(\mathcal{H})$$
>   $$0\leq A\leq B:\quad HB\in\mathcal{B}_1(\mathcal{H})\implies HA\in\mathcal{B}_1(\mathcal{H})$$

Comment: Yes, if $0 \leq A \leq B$, then for any vector $x, \langle A|H|x,x\rangle \leq \langle B|H|x,x\rangle$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: Oh really nice!! :D Can you give me a hint, please?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: that inequality is not true. If it were,  it implies that the product of positives is positive.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Positive also requires being selfadjoint which is not part of Prahlad's statement, is it? In any case I doubt it too.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Of course, you are right. This requires more thought.

Comment: @MartinArgerami $Tr(BH)=Tr(BH^{\frac{1}{2}}H^{\frac{1}{2}})=Tr(H^{\frac{1}{2}}BH^{\frac{1}{2}}) \geq Tr(H^{\frac{1}{2}}AH^{\frac{1}{2}})=Tr(AH)$ and the fact that $T$ is of trace class iff $Tr(T)<\infty$ for compact, positive $H$ show that?

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Being curious: How to show that $\sigma(A^*A)=\sigma(AA^*)$ for $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$? *(Polar Decomposition?)*

Comment: @PeterMelech: The identity $\operatorname{Tr}(H^{1/2}AH^{1/2})=\operatorname{Tr}(AH)$ for a priori $AH\notin\mathcal{B}_1(\mathcal{H})$?

Comment: @PeterMelech: Also $AH$ is not positive in general?

Comment: @Freeze_S: it's a general algebra trick. I'll reply tomorrow, as I'm travelling now.

Comment: @PeterMelech: *Pleeeease*, do not take it personal. The argumentation is from a structural point of view comparable to $\lim\int\eta(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int\lim\eta(x)\mathrm{d}x$. In other words, it is missing justification!

Comment: @Freeze_S Of course, it was just a comment, and You didn´t assume $H$ to be compact, but if You did so I think You might use it´s Schmidt expansion to show all this

Comment: @PeterMelech: Ok. :) However I don't assume it to be compact: More generally, I'd prefer to not restrict it to be compact. More specifically, in my problem it won't.

Comment: @Freeze_S: what is true is that $\sigma(AB)\cup\{0\}=\sigma(BA)\cup\{0\}$ in any ring. The trick is to show that if $C$ is an inverse for $AB-I$, then $BCA-I$ is an inverse for $BA-I$; this is just a straightforward computation .

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Ah right true that. Thanks!!

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Can you sketch the idea of your previous answer. I like the idea exploiting relations on spectrum. That might be pretty strong tool together with relations on and with numerical range Even more this might help to solve further problems of mine...

Comment: Done. I've changed it a little, since all my argument did was to prove that $X$ is trace-class if and only if $X^*$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*this is not really an answer*.

**Claim:** $X $ is trace-class if and only if $X^* $ is trace-class.

*Proof of the claim.*

\begin{align}
\text {Tr}(|X|)&=\sum \{\lambda:\ \lambda\in\sigma ((X^*X)^{1/2})\}
 =\sum \{\lambda^{1/2}:\ \lambda\in\sigma (X^*X)\}\\ \ \\
&=\sum \{\lambda^{1/2}:\ \lambda\in\sigma (XX^*)\}
=\sum \{\lambda:\ \lambda\in\sigma ((XX^*)^{1/2})\}\\ \ \\
&=\text {Tr}(|X^*|).
\end{align}

Comment: Does the second implication derive from $\sum_j(H^{\frac{1}{2}}BH^{\frac{1}{2}}\phi_j,\phi_j)\geq \sum_j (H^{\frac{1}{2}}AH^{\frac{1}{2}}\phi_j,\phi_j)$, why exactly is the last identity true ($Tr(|Y^*X^*|)=Tr(|XY|)$?

Comment: @PeterMelech: yes to your first question. As for the second, the same argument with $Y=I $ shows that $\|X\|_1=\|X^*\|_1$.

Comment: Thanks, OK, I had a typo in my comment, Your last identity reads $Tr(|Y^*X^*|)=Tr(|YX|)$, which is not that clear to me, the rest is clear..

Comment: You are right., my argument requires $X,Y $ selfadjoint. I'll delete the answer for now.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Ok so I got that $BH$ being trace class so also $HBH$ and so also $HAH$. Finally, how can I break it down to $AH$?

Comment: That's the thing. The other day I spent a couple hours trying to use that idea, but I couldn't make it work. The fact that $HAH$ is trace-class is exactly the same as saying that $A^{1/2}H$ is Hilbert-Schmidt. It is not obvious to me how that would imply that $AH$ is trace-class.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Yep, right, that is the difficulty here. Though not solved, I still like the idea of working with the spectrum as well. So let me just check off your answer?

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I hope I didn't take to much time of yours??

Comment: Not at all. I liked thinking about it, and I'm frustrated to be unable to find the right argument. That said, I don't think you should accept my answer, as it definitely is not enough to answer your question.